# How to solve this integration or does this have a closed form?

Tags: integration, closed-form

The integral I am dealing with is below.

I need to find the closed-form expression of this integral.

$$\int_0^\infty \ln\left(1+\frac{A}{1+B+Cx}\right)\frac{e^{-x/M}}{M}\,dx.$$

Here, $A$, $B$, $C$ and $M$ are constants.

How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? This question will likely get closed unless you type up what you've done so far.

Comment: For $\Re a > 0$, $\int_0^\infty \log(x+a)e^{-x} dx = \log(a) + e^a \Gamma(0,a)$ where $\Gamma(0,a)$ is the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). If the constants are positive, you can use this to express your integral in terms of incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will assume $C>0$. You can redo all of the following if it's negative. Replace $1+B+Cx$ with $y$ to get
\begin{align*}
1+B+Cx&=y \\
C\,dx &= dy \\
dx &=\frac{dy}{C}\\
-\frac{x}{M}&=-\frac{y-1-B}{CM}=-\frac{y}{CM}+\frac{1+B}{CM} \\
\int_0^\infty \ln\left(1+\frac{A}{1+B+Cx}\right)\frac{e^{-x/M}}{M}\,dx
&=\exp\left(\frac{1+B}{CM}\right)\int_{1+B}^\infty \ln\left(\frac{y+A}{y}\right)\,\frac{e^{-y/(CM)}}{CM}\,dy\\
&=\frac{e^{(1+B)/(CM)}}{CM}\int_{1+B}^\infty [\ln(y+A)-\ln(y)]\,e^{-y/(CM)}\,dy.
\end{align*}
That's about as far as I can go without machine help. The Wolfram Dev Platform will compute this, if the real part of $CM>0.$ The result is quite messy, and involves the [Meijer G function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function). I get this:

$$C M \left(e^{A/(CM)}
   G_{1,2}^{2,0}\left(\frac{A+B+1}{C M}\Bigg|
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right)-G_{1,2}^{2,0}\left(\frac{B+1}{C M}\Bigg|
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right)-\log (A+B+1) e^{A/(CM)}+\log (A+B+1) e^{-(1+B)/(CM)}+e^{A/(CM)} \log \left(\frac{A+B+1}{C M}\right)-e^{A/(CM)} \log
   \left(\frac{1}{C M}\right)+\log (B+1) \left(1-e^{-(1+B)/(CM)}\right)-\log
   \left(\frac{B+1}{C M}\right)+\log \left(\frac{1}{C
   M}\right)\right). $$